# How to make complex contains queries in Django?

Tags: python, django

I need to make query like this:

> ```
> WHERE Comment like '%ev% 3628%' or Comment like '%ew% 3628%'
> ```

the number '3628' is a parametr. So I've tried in my view:

**First try:**

```
wherestr = "Comment like '%%ev%% %s%%' or Comment like '%%ew%% %s%%'" % (rev_number, rev_number)  
comment_o = Issuecomments.objects.extra(where=[wherestr])
```

**but I've got:**
TypeError at /comments_by_rev/3628/

not enough arguments for format string

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/comments_by_rev/3628/
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

not enough arguments for format string

**Second try:**

```
comment = IssuetrackerIssuecomments.objects.filter(Q(comment__contains=rev_number), Q(comment__contains='ew') | Q(comment__contains='ev'))
```

but its not excactly the same.
Have you people of wisdom any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You need something similar to this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def myview(request):
   query = "hi" #string to search for
   items = self.filter(Q(comment__contains=query) | Q(comment__contains=query))
   ...
```

Just make sure the query string is properly escaped.

Comment: Django escapes '%' in the middle of query like that:
"%ew\% 3628%"
instead of:
"%ew% 3628%"

Comment: Not django, but sqlserver_ado db backend for mssql (in operations.py). Hashed and works.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right...  The problem is that your % are being subsituted twice.  [Django actually has a way of passing parameters in the extra clause](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) like this

```
wherestr = "Comment like '%%ev%% %s%%' or Comment like '%%ew%% %s%%'"
params = (rev_number, rev_number)
comment_o = Issuecomments.objects.extra(where=[wherestr], params=[params])
```

This is a better way of passing the parameters as it won't leave you open to SQL injection attacks like your way will.

Comment: TypeError at /comments_by_rev/3628/

not enough arguments for format string

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8001/comments_by_rev/3628/
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

not enough arguments for format string

Exception Location:  C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py in last_executed_query, line 217

Comment: I did check the above, and it worked when I tried it.

Not enough params means some mismatch between the number of `%s` in `wherestr` and the number of items in the `params` tuple - I suggest you double check them!

Comment: I tested it on MySQL and I guess it might be different on your DB backend.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/, specifically

icontains: Case-insensitive containment test.

Example: Entry.objects.get(headline__icontains='Lennon')

SQL equivalent: SELECT ... WHERE headline ILIKE '%Lennon%';

Since you're looking for a pattern like %%ev%% or %%ew%%, consider the IREGEX or REGEX versions as well?

Lastly, consider performing the search differently...perhaps parse out the interesting parts of the message and put them in their own indexed columns for querying later.  You'll regret doing this search once the table gets large:).

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm forced to use MSSql2005 and regex doas not simply works there.